# DML statement in Snowflake UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> **Can we write DML statements (Insert/Update) inside snowflake udf rather than procedure.**

Answer (score 1):

UDFs can contain SQL or JavaScript; however, DDL and DML operations are not supported in UDFs.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/ddl-udf.html#udf-management

Answer (score 0):

UDF is meant to be used in a SELECT statement by passing a column into it. If you need to run DML statement inside a UDF, I can see there is some sort of design issue here.

> UDFs can contain SQL or JavaScript; however, DDL and DML operations
> are not supported in UDFs.